# How do I convert multiple rows of data to a single one by category?

Tags: r

I need help with this issue.

Current data:

```
File                  Compound         Height
B21990_COPLT_210520   Aggricin         19760 
B21990_COPLT_210520   Ferrioxamine     5064
B21990_COPLT_210520   Betacin          101000
BA6650_CA2LT_210520   Metamin          6640 
BA6650_CA2LT_210520   Surfactin        623600
BA6650_CA2LT_210520   Alanine          6460
```

Desired file:

```
File                 High       Med       Low
B21990_COPLT_210520  Betacin    Aggricin  Ferrioxamine
BA6650_CA2LT_210520  Surfactin  NA        Metain,Alanine
```

I have ~100-200 lines of data, and need to sort them via their Height into 'High', 'Med' and 'Low' (High: Peak Height > 60 000; Med: > 15 000 but > 70 000; Low: < 15 000). Besides that, I would also need for the files to in one single line as well.

This is my current code:

```
SourceFP <- read.csv("SourceFP.csv",header=TRUE)
SourceFP %>% mutate(Category = case_when(Height>60000~'High',
                                    Height>15000~'Med',
                                    TRUE~'Low')) %>% spread(Category,Name)
```

Unfortunately, when I select the files later on, I am unable to combine the files into one line and they appear as multiple rows:

e.g.

```
File                  High           Med            Low
B21990_COPLT_210520   NA             Aggricin       NA         
B21990_COPLT_210520   NA             NA             Ferrioxamine
B21990_COPLT_210520   Betacin        NA             NA
BA6650_CA2LT_210520   NA             NA             Metamin
BA6650_CA2LT_210520   Surfactin      NA             NA
BA6650_CA2LT_210520   NA             NA             Alanine
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Generally, you are on the right path, i.e. creating your high/med/low variable and then instead of `spread` you should use `pivot_wider`.

Comment: hi, i think you need to solve the problem of columnwise combination first. In your "Desired file" you combine `Metamin,Alanine` yet there is no code or provided logic as to why those two should be combined while `Ferrioxamine` is not combined with anything.

Comment: It is determined by their `height` and their grouping into high/med/low.

Comment: What if there are multiple compounds for the same file where Height > 15000 evaluates to TRUE?

Comment: @dario for this case I will need the compounds to be separated by a comma, but located in the same position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
df$grp=ifelse(df$Height>60000,"High",ifelse(df$Height<15000,"Low","Med"))
dcast(df,File~grp,toString,value.var="Compound")

                 File      High              Low      Med
1 B21990_COPLT_210520   Betacin     Ferrioxamine Aggricin
2 BA6650_CA2LT_210520 Surfactin Metamin, Alanine
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot_wider` after dividing the data into different `Category`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

SourceFP %>% 
  mutate(Category = case_when(Height>60000~'High',
                              Height>15000~'Med',
                              TRUE~'Low')) %>%
  arrange(desc(Height)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Category, values_from = Compound, 
              values_fn = toString, id_cols = File)

#  File                High      Med      Low             
#  <chr>               <chr>     <chr>    <chr>           
#1 BA6650_CA2LT_210520 Surfactin NA       Metamin, Alanine
#2 B21990_COPLT_210520 Betacin   Aggricin Ferrioxamine
```

**data**

```
SourceFP <- structure(list(File = c("B21990_COPLT_210520", "B21990_COPLT_210520",
"B21990_COPLT_210520", "BA6650_CA2LT_210520", "BA6650_CA2LT_210520", 
"BA6650_CA2LT_210520"), Compound = c("Aggricin", "Ferrioxamine", 
"Betacin", "Metamin", "Surfactin", "Alanine"), Height = c(19760L, 
5064L, 101000L, 6640L, 623600L, 6460L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I tried this method too. However, this gives me the following error: Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. I'mnot sure what this means or how to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `dcast` to reshape your data

```
dcast(
  setDT(SourceFP)[
    ,
    Category := c("Low", "Med", "High")[as.integer(cut(Height, c(-Inf, 15000, 60000, Inf)))]
  ],
  File ~ Category,
  value.var = "Compound",
  fun = toString
)
```

which gives

```
                  File      High              Low      Med
1: B21990_COPLT_210520   Betacin     Ferrioxamine Aggricin
2: BA6650_CA2LT_210520 Surfactin Metamin, Alanine
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well :) Also just realised that setDT is in the data.table package haha. Thanks!